# passing terminal arguments into another function

Tags: c, terminal, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass the arguments from the terminal into another function.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cprint(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}

void cprint(int a, char *argv[]){
    printf(a);
    printf(argv[1]);
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'cprint'

previous implicit declaration is here
cprint(argc, arguments);
```

Any ideas how to implement my objective? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move `cprint` over `main` OR add this line `void cprint(int a, char *argv[);` over `main`

Comment: OH YES. I just had to declare the function as a header!! thanks !